# Why is there now a long list of tags and badges recently achieved by named individuals down the right hand side of the Stack Overflow homepage?

Tags: discussion, support, hot-questions, sidebar

Whilst logged into my account, there is now a long list of tags and badges recently achieved by named individuals appearing down the right hand side of my screen when I navigate to `https://stackoverflow.com/`.

I have disabled userscripts and adblockers and no difference. The few others I have asked have been unable to repro.

I am using Chrome Version 88.0.4324.190 (Official Build) (64-bit). The same with Firefox 85.0.2 (64-bit).

This is the recently earned badges list with names:

[image]

And to show you where the list appears, below [HMP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353492/hot-meta-posts-allow-for-removal-by-moderators-and-thoughts-about-future-impro), filters, watched and ignored tags there's the recent tag list, which is then followed by the recently earned badges list with Stack Overflow profile names:

[image]

<sub>[Enlarge Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdKdD.png)</sub>

Comment: I don't even have the "Recent Tags" list. Is this a feature for [users with 25k+ rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)? If so, have the individuals you asked also earned that privilege?

Comment: @41686d6564 I haven't seen it before and now I can't repro on my mac (was using Windows machine before). I doubt it is related to rep however. I wondered if it was testing for a new feature? But that said, I see little use to the recent tag list as it appears in screenshot.

Comment: I don't have 25k+ rep and I can see both "Recent Tag" and "Recent Badges" list. So not related to site analytics privilege. Don't think it's related to browser, but I'm on Firefox 86.0 on macOS. I can't remember when I first saw it, but it's been there for quite some time for me.

Comment: @GinoMempin That's helpful. Maybe I missed an announcement but then if only some users are seeing it perhaps it is A/B testing?  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: I knew this site was going to make me feel old eventually but I never imagined anything like this.

Comment: @41686d6564: This was a feature for users who were around [at least 8 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-multicollider-redesign). We earned the privilege of being old enough to have been there to see it on the home page. And now whippersnappers like QHarr get to see it there too! (I'm not even 30.)

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks :-) Impressive to not yet be 30 and have been with the site so long.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is what shows up when you have Hot Network Questions disabled in your preferences.

I've had HNQ disabled since that was an option, and ever since then I've had that recent tags and recent badges list. Those lists are what occupied that space [before HNQ existed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209906/294691) and apparently it's still there as a fallback.

[image: screenshot of the Stack Overflow homepage showing recent tags and recent badges]

If you didn't mean to disable Hot Network Questions, check your settings to see if you did it by accident.

Comment: Can you not have your cake and eat it too?  I kinda miss seeing that.

Comment: It's also appeared as a fallback for users who haven't opted out of HNQ but for some reason HNQ could not be loaded. I've seen a report to that effect, but never been able to reproduce.